# call posts groups in a page template and display post post content

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make posts, put them in groups and call those groups to a page template to display contents from those posts. Sounds pretty straight forward but I just cant seem to figure it out. There are whole bunch of examples out there but I dont seem to get it.

Attached is the workflow diagram

I am not a PHP developer so syntax is bit tricky for me and I can look through that. I guess everything has a first time.

It would be great to be able to create some sort of UI in the admin panel to assign the post groups to pages through some check boxes rather than hard coding values in a template that would be pretty awesome too. If this is too far fetched at this point lets skip this part. But eventually I would love to frame work it[image: work flow diagram]

I am adding the screen grab of my dashboad when i am creating a new page. I am not seeing anything like visual composer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

when you are creating new page there is screen option for visual content composer and in that there is option like post type. In that you can select type of post and also category which you want to show.

Comment: @Aditi-- I am not seeing anything like your screen. I just added a screen grab

Comment: @Aditi-- I solved it through some custom php since I couldnt make to work the way you guys were directing me to..here is what i ended up doing

<?php 
    if(is_page('information-architecture-2')){
     query_posts('category_name=information-architecture');
     }if(is_page('code-samples')){
     query_posts('category_name=code-samples');
     }if(is_page('illustrations-collection')){
     query_posts('category_name=illustration-samples');
     }
   ?>

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to add 3 categories in posts section when you adding new post then these categories are appearing on right side. categorize each posts and when you hit the category 1 you can just see category one posts like wise 2 and 3.
see the image.
[image]

Comment: @yahya-- i am really not seeing that button. I am using wordpress default 2012.. am I missing something here?

Comment: can u send me the screen shot which button is missing

Comment: @yahya-- I added a screen grab of my dash. See if that helps

Comment: Visual composer is just for designing the text.Rather then pages you just have add posts and categories them .When adding post on the right side you can see the categories.